# Set a Date field's default to Today

Tags: javascript

I'm working with CaseBox, though this question probably applies to a wide range of Javascript applications.

We have a bunch of data entry forms that include the date of entry.  In most cases the date of entry will be the current day; some use cases exist where it's not.  So we want the date field to default to the current day.

In CaseBox, I can set the `Config` property of the field to provide a fixed default date, like so:

```
{
  "value": "2016-10-24"
}
```

What I want, but isn't succeeding, would be more like this:

```
{
  "value": Today() //possibly: new Date()
}
```

I've done quite a bit of research, and have yet to discover a way to do this in the `Config` property.  I may have to go into the code and specify that all date fields have a default value of `new Date()`.  Meanwhile, is there any way to do this without changing the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code:

Use Common function for get today date :

```
function GetTodayDate(){
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
return today;   
}
```

and use this funcation in your code like below:

```
{
  "value": GetTodayDate() //possibly: new Date()
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v46s2x6c/)

Hope it helps you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "value": new Date(Date.now())
}
```

How you format the `datetime` after that is up to you.

You can write a function that returns todays date in `ISO` or however you like.

Comment: Nope, the date field had no default value.  Pity, I thought that was going to work, so +1 for your effort.

Comment: You should post your code so we can get a broader idea of what you want.

Comment: Will do, as soon as I can get to the source code.  (There's logistical issues at the moment, that should be resolved Real Soon Now.)